# included php file function global var problem

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

I have a index.php file, i include functions.php

functions.php

```
function myfunction($var1, &$array_work) {

  $array_work = array();
  global $array_work;

  array_push($array_work, "Test");
}


$var1 = 2;
myfunction($var1, $array_work);

print "<pre>";
print_r($array_work);
print "</pre>";
```

Everthing works, when i call the file direct (functions.php), but when i include this file into the index.php it doesnt work?

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
```

this works now for me:

```
function myfunction($var1, &$array_work) {
  array_push($array_work, "Test");
}


$var1 = 2;
$array_work = array();
myfunction($var1, $array_work);

print "<pre>";
print_r($array_work);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Why do you use both `global` and a reference parameter?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: i want to create an array in function and use it outside the function

Comment: Isn't that what the reference parameter does? Why do you ALSO need to use `global`?

Comment: If you want to create it inside, you don't need to pass it as a parameter. Just create and return it.

Comment: for return i want to use other var

Comment: Then return both of them in another array or in an object.

Comment: Does the function really initialize to an empty array every time you call it?

Comment: @Barmer yep have this error

Comment: this works now: